# SQL Server 2019 cross-database function call permission

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permission-denied, cross-database

I have come across some interesting behaviour in SQL Server 2019 - it does not seem to occur in earlier versions.

If, in database1, I call a function in the same database, which calls a function in database2, which SELECTS a table in database2, I get "The SELECT permission was denied on the object '{TableName}', database '{DbName}', schema 'dbo'."

If, instead, I call the function in database2 directly (without using a function in database1), the query executes successfully.

[image: Architecture diagram]

My question is: what is the logic behind this? I don't understand why I am allowed to read a table in another database, without the SELECT permission, through a function, but ***not*** when I call that function using a function in my current database! Is it due to the function preventing the passing on of permissions? I am assuming at the moment that this is an intended change - but I don't understand the logic behind it.

Below is some code demonstrating the behaviour in a simple way.

```
/*******************************************
SET UP
*******************************************/
CREATE DATABASE TestDb1
GO
CREATE DATABASE TestDb2
GO

CREATE LOGIN [TestLogin] WITH PASSWORD = '123456a.'
GO

--Create users in each database and add to roles.
USE TestDb1
CREATE USER [TestUser] FOR LOGIN [TestLogin]
CREATE ROLE Db1Role
ALTER ROLE Db1Role ADD MEMBER [TestUser]

USE TestDb2
CREATE USER [TestUser] FOR LOGIN [TestLogin]
CREATE ROLE Db2Role
ALTER ROLE Db2Role ADD MEMBER [TestUser]

--Create table in db1, but do no GRANTs on it.
USE TestDb1
CREATE TABLE dbo._testDb1Table (Col1 INT)
GO

--Create a function in db1, and GRANT EXECUTE.
CREATE FUNCTION dbo._TestDb1Function()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT = (SELECT TOP (1) Col1 FROM dbo._testDb1Table)
    RETURN @Result
END
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo._TestDb1Function TO Db1Role
GO

--Create a function in db2, and GRANT EXECUTE.
USE TestDb2
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo._TestDb2Function()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT = (SELECT TestDb1.dbo._TestDb1Function())
    RETURN @Result
END
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo._TestDb2Function TO Db2Role
GO

/*******************************************
TESTS
*******************************************/
USE TestDb2

--Querying TestDb1 by calling the TestDb2 function directly works.
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'TestLogin'
SELECT TestDb1.dbo._TestDb1Function()
REVERT
GO

--Querying TestDb2 through a scalar function in db2 doesn't work.
--The SELECT permission was denied on the object '_testDb1Table', database 'TestDb1', schema 'dbo'.
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'TestLogin'
SELECT dbo._TestDb2Function()
REVERT
GO

/*******************************************
TIDY UP
*******************************************/
USE [master]
DROP LOGIN [TestLogin]
DROP DATABASE TestDb1
DROP DATABASE TestDb2
```

Comment: I assume this doesn't happen in prior versions? I would *suggest* (if not) that it's an inlining "feature". But having a function that calls a function in another database, that then performs a `SELECT` on another table sounds like a design problem.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you [switch off scalar function inlining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15#disabling-scalar-udf-inlining-without-changing-the-compatibility-level)? If so, you can [upvote](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/39168094-sql-server-2019-scalar-function-inlining-breaks-ow).

Comment: You seem to have hit the nail on the head with scalar UDF inlining. I am not sure I understand exactly why this results from that, but I can confirm that adding a hint to the SELECT statement which doesn't work, to disable UDF inlining, makes it work.  Thanks for the help. i.e. SELECT dbo._TestDb2Function()
OPTION (USE HINT('DISABLE_TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING'));

Comment: It's possible that this was solved in CU-5 (Cumulative update n° 5). Perhaps try update, see if that helps.

Comment: I've just tested the same code using SQL Server 2019 CU5 and it behaves in the same way unfortunately.

Comment: It also behaves the same way in CU6.

Answer (score 1):

As per helpful comments by GSerg and Larnu, this behaviour appears to be caused by the scalar UDF inlining feature, added in SQL Server 2019.

It can be fixed by [disabling scalar UDF inlining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15#disabling-scalar-udf-inlining-without-changing-the-compatibility-level) at the database level, in the function definition, or using a query hint.

Edit: as per the answer by Razvan Socol, this has been fixed in SQL Sever 2019 CU9.

Here is the same code as given in the original question, but with these 3 possible solutions inserted into the appropriate places (commented out). Uncommenting any of these 3 solutions allows the script to run without error in SQL Server 2019.

```
/*******************************************
SET UP
*******************************************/
CREATE DATABASE TestDb1
CREATE DATABASE TestDb2
GO
--SOLUTION 1: Turn off scalar UDF inlining at the database level.
--USE TestDb2
--ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING = OFF;
GO

CREATE LOGIN [TestLogin] WITH PASSWORD = '123456a.'
GO

--Create users in each database and add to roles.
USE TestDb1
CREATE USER [TestUser] FOR LOGIN [TestLogin]
CREATE ROLE Db1Role
ALTER ROLE Db1Role ADD MEMBER [TestUser]

USE TestDb2
CREATE USER [TestUser] FOR LOGIN [TestLogin]
CREATE ROLE Db2Role
ALTER ROLE Db2Role ADD MEMBER [TestUser]

--Create table in db1, but do no GRANTs on it.
USE TestDb1
CREATE TABLE dbo._testDb1Table (Col1 INT)
GO

--Create a function in db1, and GRANT EXECUTE.
CREATE FUNCTION dbo._TestDb1Function()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT = (SELECT TOP (1) Col1 FROM dbo._testDb1Table)
    RETURN @Result
END
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo._TestDb1Function TO Db1Role
GO

--Create a function in db2, and GRANT EXECUTE.
USE TestDb2
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo._TestDb2Function()
RETURNS INT
--SOLUTION 2: Turn off scalar UDF inlining for the function.
--WITH INLINE = OFF
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT = (SELECT TestDb1.dbo._TestDb1Function())
    RETURN @Result
END
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo._TestDb2Function TO Db2Role
GO

/*******************************************
TESTS
*******************************************/
USE TestDb2

--Querying TestDb1 by calling the TestDb2 function directly works.
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'TestLogin'
SELECT TestDb1.dbo._TestDb1Function()
REVERT
GO

--Querying TestDb2 through a scalar function in db2 doesn't work.
--The SELECT permission was denied on the object '_testDb1Table', database 'TestDb1', schema 'dbo'.
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'TestLogin'
SELECT dbo._TestDb2Function()
--SOLUTION 3: Turn off scalar UDF inlining for the query which calls the function.
--OPTION (USE HINT('DISABLE_TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING')); --Added line
REVERT
GO

/*******************************************
TIDY UP
*******************************************/
USE [master]
DROP LOGIN [TestLogin]
DROP DATABASE TestDb1
DROP DATABASE TestDb2
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in SQL Server 2019, caused by [scalar UDF inlining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15).
It was fixed in [SQL Server 2019 CU9](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5000642-cumulative-update-9-for-sql-server-2019-97ad5c3e-e002-4b6d-b566-698bf70ca44a) (published in February 2021).
For more details see [KB4538581](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4538581-fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2019-f52d3759-a8b7-a107-1ab9-7fbee264dd5d).

Comment: Thanks for this update. I can verify that the code example above which demonstrates the problem is no longer a problem in CU9.